# Is it possible to convert a batch and txt file to an exe file?

Tags: batch-file

So I have a batch file that imports text from a separate txt document and displays it to the user, and I would like to convert them both into a single exe file, meaning the user wouldn't see or be able to change the txt file. Is this possible or am I just speaking non-sense?

Comment: When you googled "compile batch file into exe", what did you find? Please take the basic step of typing something into a search engine.

Comment: Yes, by rewriting the code in batch file in programming languages like C, C++, C#, Delphi, etc., compile the code and of course test the executable containing now not anymore a script code which need a script interpreter for execution, but native processor instructions for direct execution by the processor for which the source code was compiled. All "bat to exe" converter do nothing else than packing a batch file (without or with other files) into an archive and on execution extract them to `%TEMP%` and execute them with `cmd.exe /C`. So a user can grab the files from `%TEMP%` on execution.

Answer (score 4):

There is a very easy way to do this and you don't need to download any 3rd party tools to do so. Using a windows utility called `iexpress` you can create a self extracting directive.

---

This will walk you through how to convert your script to an *.EXE*

1. Firstly, open iexpress. (Press *WindowsHome+R* - Type `iexpress`)
2. Under **Package purpose**, select "*Extract files and run installation command*"
3. Name your package
4. Under **Confirmation prompt**, select "*No prompt*"
5. Under **License agreement**, select "*Do not display a license*"
6. Now for your **Packaged files**, you will want to select your batch file and your text file. It's important that you `CD %~dp0` to the batch location as the cabinet will extract the files to directory in your `%temp%` folder during execution. Bellow will be an example:

**textfile.txt**

```
Hello agent! Your secret code is:
Apple
```

**x.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
@CD %~dp0

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (textfile.txt) do echo %%x
echo. & pause
```

7. Under **Install Program to Launch**, you will want to put `cmd.exe /c x.bat` in for the "*Install Program*". Leave "*Post Install Command*" set as *None*.
8. Under **Show window**, have it set to "*Default*"
9. Under **Package Name and Options**, Under options, check "*Hide File Extracting Progress Animation from User*"

---

Create the package and wa-laa, your batch and txt is now an .EXE

Comment: what should I enter as the target path and filename for the package, under 'Package Name and Options' ? And where is the final .EXE saved?

Comment: The .exe is created and then disappears after a few seconds.. Do you know why this may be happening?

Comment: @walksignison The `Package Name` is where you wish to save the package you're creating. Browse for an location ex: Desktop.

Comment: I am trying to run a batch script which simply starts an application and passes a bash script to that application as an argument.. it works when I simply run the batch script in the same directory as the bash script. But when I package it as above, only the batch script seems to run i.e. the application starts. But, the bash script is not run within it. Do you think you can help with this?

Comment: @walksignison Sounds like you need to `CD` to the called batch location using `CD %~dp0`. Put it at the top of your script. The extracted files of the package are saved to your `%temp%` directory (In a labed folder). Try playing around and or checking to make sure it works there manually. This will let you know if its just a package script error or not.